# Derivatives of Finsler metric in the Riemannian case

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, information-geometry, finsler-geometry

I'm trying to wrap my head around this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11401-005-0333-3) of Zhongmin Shenfor my Master thesis. In Proposition 8.2, he assures that in the Riemannian case in which $L(x,y)=g_{ij}(x)y^iy^j$, given the equality
$$ L_{x^ky^l}y^k = 2L_{x^l}, $$
the following is true:
$$\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^k}(x) + \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i}(x) = 2 \frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l}(x). $$
I think the Euler theorem ($L_{y^i}y^i = 2L$) must be used somewhere to arrive to the result, but I'm very lost. Can you kindly give some guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $L_{x^ky^l}y^k = 2L_{x^l}$. We have $$L(x,y)=g_{ij}(x)y^iy^j.$$ Differentiating w.r.t. $x^k$ we find that
$$L_{x^k}=\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k}y^iy^j \text{, [$x,y$ are omitted for simplicity.]}$$
Differentiating w.r.t. $y^l$ we get
$$L_{x^ky^l}=\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial y^l}y^j+\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial y^l}y^i$$
$$\implies L_{x^ky^l}y^k=\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial y^i}{\partial y^l}y^jy^k+\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k} \frac{\partial y^j}{\partial y^l}y^iy^k$$
$$\implies L_{x^ky^l}y^k=\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k} \delta^i_l y^jy^k+\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x^k} \delta^j_l y^iy^k,\text{ $\delta^i_j$ being Kronecker's delta}$$
$$\implies L_{x^ky^l}y^k=\frac{\partial g_{lj}}{\partial x^k} y^jy^k+\frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^k} y^iy^k,\text{ $i=l$ on first term $j=l$ on second term}$$
Interchanging $j$ and $k$ in the first term and replacing $j$ by $i$ on that term we get
$$L_{x^ky^l}y^k = \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i} + \frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^k}.$$ In similar approach it can be shown that
$$2L_{x^l} = 2 \frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l}$$ by suitable change of dummy index.

Since $L_{x^ky^l}y^k = 2L_{x^l}$ holds so we have $\displaystyle \frac{\partial g_{il}}{\partial x^k} + \frac{\partial g_{kl}}{\partial x^i} = 2 \frac{\partial g_{ik}}{\partial x^l}$.

Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you! It helped me 